# Liip - Resize image only if bigger than expected

Tags: php, symfony, liipimaginebundle

I'm using Symfony 4.2 and Liip Imagine bundle.
I have a filter like this :

```
live_feed_message:
    jpeg_quality:          40
    png_compression_level: 9
    filters:
      relative_resize:
        widen: 1024
```

But in the case that image sent is smaller than 1024px it resize to 1024px.

I would like a filter that resize the image **only** in case the image is bigger.

I searched and I don't found any solution for this.
Does anyone had this issue ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: get filesize and compare it to your ideal size. if bigger, resize it otherwise leave it

Comment: I would be able to do it with custom code. But I'm asking with Liip Imagine which is a bundle to apply filter on images. So instead of doing custom code, I would like to know if someone know how to do it with Liip Imagine

Comment: The only solution I found for now is to use a thumbnail filter with `allow_upscale`at false. But I already read that thumbnails could produce some performance issue... So I avoid using it

Comment: I am not aware of `Liip`. I gave solution according to `PHP` basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. I already tried it but not correctly I think.
Now it's working. Instead of using `relative_resize` filter, use `downscale` filter.

Documentation :

`The built-in downscale filter performs sizing transformations (specifically image down-scaling). This filter exposed a number of down scale options which may be used to configure its behavior.`

[*Relative resize filter documentation*](https://symfony.com/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/current/filters/sizing.html#relative-resize)